# cant figure out how to fix this error in Python class

Tags: python-2.7

I am beginner in Python and try to figure out what is wrong and how to fix this short python code:

```
from time import *
class Stopwatch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
    def start(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.start_time = clock()
            self.running = True
        else:
            print('Stopwatch already running')
    def stop(self):
        if self.running:
            self.elapsed += clock() - self.start_time
            self.running = False
        else:
            print('stopwatch not running')
    def reset(self):
        self.start_time = self.elapsed = 0
        self.running = False
    def elapsed(self):
        if not self.running:
            return self.elapsed
        else:
            print("stopwatch must be stopped")
            return None

timer = Stopwatch()
timer.start()
sleep(2)
print('I am awake \n')
timer.stop()
print(timer.elapsed())
```

---> i get this error saying **TypeError: 'float' object is not callable**
But why 'float' is not callable?
Thanks for your help
Howard

Answer (score 0):

You have a function named `elapsed` in your `Stopwatch` class. That's fine. However, in the `stop` method you set `self.elapsed` to be a float:

```
self.elapsed += clock() - self.start_time
```

When you call `timer.elapsed()`, Python isn't sure which `elapsed` you're referring to. You've reassigned `self.elapsed` to be a float. It complains and throws an error because you cannot invoke a float as a function.

Change the name of the function, and the error isn't thrown. For example,

```
def time_elapsed(self):
    if not self.running:
        return self.elapsed
    else:
        print("stopwatch must be stopped")
        return None

...

print(timer.time_elapsed())
```